# Prettier In VS Code keeps trimming space between code

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, editor

What problem is that. In my JSX, I want to put space between . But after I hit CTRL+S. I run prettier in VS Code and prettier is removing that space that I put in JSX.

This is [my change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap0UK.png)

This is [after prettier formatted my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ncDH.png)

Comment: When you mouse over the red underline, what does it say?

Comment: You can try turning off the Format On Save setting by going to VS Code Settings.

Comment: @NicholasTower it says, (no-trailing-spaces) I fixed this. But still problems stays

Answer (score 0):

In short, use 'Ctrl+k s'.

To save the page without formatting,
press (Ctrl+k), leave pressed buttons and then press 's'.

Comment: Does it open a keyboard shortcut page ?